# Manually invalidate NHibernate 2nd level cache

Tags: nhibernate

I wan't to manually invalidate (refresh) the 2nd level cache. How can I do that?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985749/nhibernate-second-level-cache-with-external-updates

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear the entire second level cache in NHibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660714/how-to-clear-the-entire-second-level-cache-in-nhibernate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SessionFactory.EvictQueries();
foreach (var collectionMetadata in this._SessionFactory.GetAllCollectionMetadata())
        SessionFactory.EvictCollection(collectionMetadata.Key);
foreach (var classMetadata in this._SessionFactory.GetAllClassMetadata())
        SessionFactory.EvictEntity(classMetadata.Key);
```

Comment: Yes, and I love it :-) Actually, I knew I had got it from someone but I didn't remember it was your.